# Packaging py2app app with productbuild

Tags: python, macos, app-store, py2app, productbuild

I am using pyobjc to create my mac app. I generated the .app executable using py2app using the command `python setup.py py2app`. I am now trying to submit this app to the app store. In order to do this, I need to convert it into a .pkg file. I am doing this using the command `productbuild --content dist/MaApp.app dist/MyApp.pkg`. The .pkg file is successfully created and on double clicking it, I am able to install my application. I even get the 'Installation was successful' screen of the installer. However, I am not able to find the installed application at the end of this process. I am not getting the usual screen which asks the user to drag the app to the application folder. Do I need to make any modifications to the build process to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: When using an installer the files are installed wherever you've specified. There is no need to ask the user to drag the app to somewhere.

Comment: I don't see the app in the folder.I even tried using the terminal.It seems to successfully install but I m not able to see the app.sudo installer -store -pkg "Projectplace.pkg" -target /
installer: Note: running installer as an admin user (instead of root) gives better Mac App Store fidelity
installer: Warning: Projectplace.pkg is not signed for store submission
installer: Installation Check: Passed
installer: Volume Check: Passed
installer: Starting install
installer: Install 0.0% complete
installer: Install 96.3% complete
installer: Install 100.0% complete
installer: Finished install

Comment: Are you sure the app has been designated to install into `/Applications`, and not `~/Applications`? The installer log should also tell you exactly what transpired during the install.

Comment: I don't see any logs in console as well. I only see the following lines:29/09/14 3:35:15.025 pm launchservicesd[75]: Application App:"Installer" asn:0x0-3cf3cf pid:46740 refs=7 @ 0x7fe53241fef0 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontApps ( ( "LSApplication:0x0-0x3d03d0 pid=46747 "SecurityAgent"")), so denying. : LASSession.cp #1481 SetFrontApplication() q=LSSession 100004/0x186a4 queue
29/09/14 3:35:15.025 pm WindowServer[135]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to Installer, psn 0x0-0x3cf3cf, securitySessionID=0x186a4, err=-13066

Comment: Installer has it's own log `Window > Installer Log` ( ⌘ L ).

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the installer log in the question. Even there I don't see any info about the final location

Comment: It looks like you've got it installing into: `Users/pradeep/desktop_documents/packaging/osx/dist/app_name.app` (line 4).

Comment: Yes..but I don't find it there after the installation. It is really strange. Is it possible that there is some problem because it is not code signed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be due to the fact that I did not sign my application. After I signed it, I see that the unpacked application in the /Applications folder!